# Nestat -ano what does it mean?

Tags: windows, netstat

I tried checking my PC if there are some loggers installed and what I get was:

TCP 192.168.1.7:2642    192.168.1.2:445    ESTABLISHED    4

When I checked in my Task Manager it says system? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 445 is reserved for Microsoft directory services (SMB). This particular line shows that your machine (192.168.1.7) is accessing files through Microsoft DS on that 192.168.1.2 machine. Your machine has used an ephemeral port for the connection.

If a keylogger was installed, this shows your machine has an active connection to 192.168.1.2. This would assume the software is using SMB of course.

You can try to resolve the hostname with `ping -a 192.168.1.2`, but I doubt this is a keylogger. Many things use SMB/CIFS.